# How to find definition of user defined function in AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

A co-worker at one point in time has defined a function in AWS Redshift. I have some doubts about its results and would like to see the code behind the function.

Is there any query I can do (or another method) that returns this code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
select * from pg_proc where proname ilike '%<function_name>%'
```

In the column: `prosrc` you can find the function definition. It seemed empty in SQLWorkbenchJ, but the code revealed itself after a double-click.